# Adding iframe and paragraph elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add iframe element to the page and then add `<p>` element inside that iframe.
I tried this:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.frameBorder = 1;
iframe.width = "500px";
iframe.height = "250px";
iframe.id = "iframe";

var p = document.createElement('p');
iframe.appendChild(p);
document.getElementById("div").appendChild(iframe); //this is a div  that I have in body.
```

The iframe is added to the page but P is not added into iframe(iframe's body)

Comment: Is `div` the correct ID attribute of your div element?

Comment: sure, the iframe is added but P is not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In modern browsers, you use the contentDocument attribute.  In others, you have to use contentWindow.document.  You create the paragraph using the iframe's document, in the onload event.  So:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.frameBorder = 1;
iframe.width = "500px";
iframe.height = "250px";
iframe.id = "iframe";

iframe.onload = function()
{
    var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var p = doc.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = "Paragraph in iframe";
    doc.body.appendChild(p);
};

document.getElementById("div").appendChild(iframe); //this is a div  that I have in body.
```

I made a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Fw5D/4/).

Also, I recommend you don't use ids that are the same as the tag name.  It could become confusing.

Comment: thank you very much! I kept trying for hours without using the onload-function - it just did not work. tried your solution and it worked at once!

Answer (score 1):

hopefully this will get you going in the right direction:

```
var p = document.createElement('p');

var iFrmDocument = (iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument);
if (iFrmDocument.document) iFrmDocument=iFrmDocument.document;
iFrmDocument.appendChild(p);

document.getElementById("div").appendChild(iframe);
```

Does that make sense? It's a bit of a necessary detour when dealing with [i]Frames